# Too complicated Typescript question. Dynamic object references

Tags: typescript

So, I have a query that either returns the full object OR a reference to a path within the object. So, I have a base type for the object, but if you pass in this "path" I don't know how to apply the type...ala.

As an example:

```
type Product {
   id: number,
   name: string,
   size: EnumSizes
   color: Array<string>,
   someNestedKey: {
       id: number,
       count: number
   }
}
```

some queryGetter:

```
const product: Product = getProductQueryCache(); // empty returns the full object
const someValue: Product['name']???? = getQueryCache('name'); // returns just the name, but wouldn't I "type" it in the query? How would I do that?

   function getProductQueryCache(value: string | null) {
      const product = getCache('product'); // returns everything..
      if (!value) return product

      return get(product, value, null); // HOW TO TYPE THIS or even should?

   }
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting and make sure your code is a [mcve] - you have a typo `getQueyCache`, and your `get` function is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Do you want to return an object or string within method?

Comment: If whether you return an object or a path depends on the value argument then what you want is an overloaded function with different definitions for a string value and a null value.  But I’m not 100% clear on this code — is the object path just a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function to be accepting optional keys of Product. And for the return type check the type of the value. If it's within the keys of the `Product` the result will be the value of that key, and the `Product` otherwise

```
function getProductQueryCache<K extends keyof Product>(value?: K): typeof value extends K ? Product[K] : Product {
    const product = getCache('product'); // returns everything..
    if (!value) return product

    return get(product, value, null); // HOW TO TYPE THIS or even should?
}

const id = getProductQueryCache('id') // number

const size = getProductQueryCache('size') // EnumSizes

const prod = getProductQueryCache() // Product

const NA = getProductQueryCache('non-existing') // not assignable
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=66&pln=17&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEGUCWAvYBnKBvAsAKCkKgHJ1iAaEiCkgG2PwF998AXATwAdgoAFAJwD2AEzABjVlAC82fEShJhALijwARsH7k5REAEMIwFelb8kIAObaCRdKiOx4yNOh2Exg2oP4qAgv349dgAeEzNLAD5reXRBQwA5DFZgYQBpYHYVXBt5QkUVdU1o3PdBMBBWAsgNfjcoZjwGljwAM3KJJEEQKAtgVgERcVYARTBNdgBhPTEAC2Bg1KhgAA9kkGFMAGsMwRa+IVEJCIAKADc9WjGAfhVUgEoVDm5dqHPLnhW1jahFq-3BiQAbVSAF0oCoBodJNl5B4QCYoJwDkNpD0+lNZsBjsQkQDWMQ7gBuKAAehJUH4fTA-HhS1O41YM3MFgAdCy6kg9scAIRvMZ3ClUmmI5ESZrySmsandXqsY64qGUPnASjgWi0Imk8kACQA8gB1KAAFV1xoAmrwYMbtQBJBBQbx00BQdAzMq0YRXJjNOEIxSo2WQoajcYYubYxQErWqaqaH1dBF2NABvpBiQh-iTabh0j2KNkxyQZwYePwyQKlP9UUjMaZsNYgUFtOsUsI+K+SvNjNZzHYkBdAC0KyQJmZ+fJ-ckenQdgs+jUtGAQA)